# jQuery UI tabs: Do not redirect to target selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jQuery tabs on my two tab form, everything is working and almost identical to the demo structure.

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-one">Tab 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-two">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

If I wanted to have the **Tab 2** to open instead of the first (default), I will have just this URL: `http://localhost/path/#tabs-two`

However, I noticed something, right after the onload it is going to section of `<a href="#tabs-two">Tab 2</a>` which I do not want because it is somewhere in the middle of the page. Is there something I can do to prevent this?

Comment: `$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 1 });`

Comment: your tab container is not proper.... the tab target elements must be within the `tabs` div

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QPcxe/1/

Comment: I know it is selecting the tab I wanted, my only concern is that it loads the page then automatically goes to the `<a href="#tabs-two">Tab 2</a>` which is somewhere in the middle of the page.

Comment: I think it is not possible, It is default browser behaviour, you can change the id of your element. You can not control that because it executes before any javascript on your page executes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this

Initialize the tabs with the active option specified:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ active: 1 });
```

REFERENCE

http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active

Answer (score 0):

You should use jquery to load the tab on page load depending on the hash.
In the links provide a different id than the tab ids. ie, stabs-two for the tabs-two

```
<a href="#stabs-two">Tab 2</a>
```

eg.

```
var hash = document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#')+1) ;
if(hash != ""){
   var tabId = hash.substring(1);
   var index = $('#tabs ul').index($('#'+tabId));
   $('#tabs ul').tabs('select', index);
}
```

This will solve the auto scroll to the element with id same as hash in URL.